# Call script from script

Tags: bash, variables

I have a bash script A from which I'd like to call bash script B. I'd like to declare a number of paths in B, call B from A and fetch the paths..is it possible?  If so, how do I achieve it? The scripts are located in the same folder.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it would be easier to just source the scriptB from scriptA?

```
. ./scriptB
```

This way they are run in same shell and all variables are shared.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this.  One way is to echo the paths in scriptB and set a variable in scriptA to capture the output:

In scriptA

```
paths=$(./scriptB)
```